# sometimes UINavigationBar does not update its header on screen change

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UICollectionViewController` for my menu screen in my iOS app, if I click on an element I get to another view(mostly a `UITableViewController`), but sometimes(maybe 1 out of 50 tries) I get to the right screen, but the `UINavigationController` does not change his header, so the title is still "Menu" an I have no chance to get out of this view because there is no "Back"-Button on the `NavigationController`

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please share the screen shot.It will make easy to answer

Comment: as mentioned this happens very rare, I will share one when it occurs again. But for now I try to explain it better.
I have my menu where the Title of the UINavigationController is "Menu" when I push a new ViewController sometimes the title does not change and there is no Back-Button added to the NavigationController , so there is no way to get back to the menu.

Comment: Any such thing HidesBackButton is there in your code

Comment: No, but the Problem is not only the Back button, also the Title is not set correctly, It seems that NavigationController's Header is not updated properly

Comment: try to set title in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: you need to share your code if you could not solve it